# How to bind input value from select with the fields of the message angular

Tags: angular, filtering

I have an app with the search which filters by header, but I want to adjust this search with select/option (so if I choose header) and write header in the field of the search it will search by header , if I select an option with tag or author it will search by author or tag

My component:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {Message} from "../message";
import {MessageApiService} from "../message-api.service";
import {ToastrService} from "ngx-toastr";
import {UserService} from "../../user/user.service";
import {User} from "../../user/user";
import {TokenStorageService} from "../../auth/token-storage.service";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {MessageService} from "../message.service";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-index',
  templateUrl: './index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index.component.css']
})
export class IndexComponent implements OnInit {

  user?: User;
  deleted = false;
  info:any;
  totalLength!:number;
  page:number=1;
  private _searchVar!: string;
  searchType!:string;

  constructor(public messageApiService: MessageApiService,
              private toastr: ToastrService,
              private userService: UserService,
              private token:TokenStorageService,
              public messageService:MessageService) {
  }


  get searchVar(): string {
    return this._searchVar;
  }

  set searchVar(value: string) {
    this._searchVar = value;
    this.messageService.filteredMessages = this.filterMessages(value);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.info = {
      token: this.token.getToken(),
      username: this.token.getUsername(),
      authorities: this.token.getAuthorities(),
      firstName: this.token.getFirstName(),
      lastName:this.token.getLastName()
    };
    this.messageApiService.getAll().subscribe((data: Message[]) => {
      this.messageService.messages = data;
      this.messageService.filteredMessages = this.messageService.messages;
      this.messageService.filteredMessages = this.filterMessages(this.searchVar);
      this.totalLength = data.length;
      console.log(this.messageService.messages);
    })
    this.userService.find(this.token.getUseId()).subscribe((user) => this.user = user);
  }

  deletePost1(id: number) {
    this.messageApiService.delete(id).subscribe(res => {
        this.toastr.success("Post Deleted");
        this.messageService.filteredMessages = this.messageService.filteredMessages.filter(item => item.id !== id);
        console.log('Post deleted successfully!');
      },
      () => {
        this.toastr.error("Can't delete! Something went wrong","Error")
      })
  }

  infoPost(messageId: number) {
    //showModalInfo(messageId);
    console.log("info post:" + messageId)
  }

  filterMessages(searchString: string) {
    console.log("search type: "+ this.searchType);
    return this.messageService.messages.filter(message => message.header.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.toLowerCase()) !== -1);

  }
}
```

My messageService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Message} from "./message";
import {MessageApiService} from "./message-api.service";
import {ToastrService} from "ngx-toastr";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MessageService {
  messages:Message[] = [];
  filteredMessages:Message[]=[];


  constructor(private messageApiService:MessageApiService,
              private toastr:ToastrService) { }

  likeTheMessage(id:number){
    this.messageApiService.like(id).subscribe(res=>{
        const selectedMessage=this.filteredMessages.find((message)=> message.id===id);
        if(selectedMessage){
          selectedMessage.likeCount++;
        }
        this.toastr.success("Liked!","",{positionClass:'toast-top'});
        console.log('Liked!');
      },
      () => {
        this.toastr.error("U already done IT!","",{positionClass:'toast-top'})
      })
  }

  unlikeTheMessage(id:number){

    this.messageApiService.unlike(id).subscribe(res=>{
        const selectedMessage=this.filteredMessages.find((message)=> message.id===id);
        if(selectedMessage){
          selectedMessage.likeCount--;
        }
        this.toastr.success("UnLiked!","",{positionClass:'toast-top'});
        console.log('Unliked!');
      },
      () => {
        // const options= { positionClass:'toast-custom' };
        this.toastr.error("U already done IT!","",{positionClass:'toast-top'})
      })
  }
}
```

html code:

```
<div>
      <select class="form-select" [(ngModel)] = "searchType">
        <option value="header">Header</option>
        <option value="tag">Tag</option>
        <option value="authorUsername">Author</option>
      </select>
      <input  class="" placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="searchVar">
    </div>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let message of messageService.filteredMessages |paginate: {
  itemsPerPage:3
  ,currentPage: page
  ,totalItems:totalLength
  }">
    <app-messageblock [message]="message" (deleteEvent)="deletePost1($event)" (infoEvent)="infoPost($event)"></app-messageblock>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

For now, my app filters only by message.header

and i want to expand the quantity of the search options with this select , so i need to bind the value from this to the fields of the message

My message interface:

```
export interface Message {
  id: number;
  header: string;
  text: string;
  tag: string;
  authorUsername: string;
  likeCount: number;
  userId:number;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what your specific question is here.... If you're hoping for the app to "auto" filter based on the search term, you'll need some way for the app to detect that the dropdown changed. I'd recommend using an angular form control there and simply subscribe to the valueChanges observable. Once you detect the dropdown changes, call your filter method to filter the data using the new criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try something like this: (with react.js)

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (graduates?.length > 0) {
      const filteredGraduates = graduates?.filter(graduate => {
        if (
          graduate.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) ||
          graduate.workplace?.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) ||
          graduate.eworkplace?.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) ||
          graduate.role?.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) ||
          graduate.erole?.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) ||
          graduate.center.includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
        ) {
          return graduate
        }
        return null
      })
      setFilteredGraduates(filteredGraduates)
    }
  }, [searchTerm])
```